# create sequences of people per pages by nationalties

Tags: r

I am working on historical census registers.

I have nationalities like english, french or portuguese  30 people are recorded for a complete page.

For "small" nationalities we don't have a complete page (people <30).
For "big" nationalities we  have  complete pages and the last page is always incomplete.

I want to identify each people with 3 informations : nationality, page number and row number

The data can be stored in two types of data frames :

First data frame (faster data entry) :

```
nationality <- c("english", "french", "portuguese")
number_of_complete_pages <- c(10, 3, 8)
number_of_people_last_page <- c(5,12,1)
register <- data.frame(nationality, number_of_complete_pages, number_of_people_last_page)
avg_people_per_complete_page <-  30
```

Second data frame in long format (I think it's the better one):

```
nationality <- c("english", "english", "portuguese")
page number <- c(1, 2, 1)
number_of_people_page <- c(30,30,30)
register <- data.frame(nationality, number_of_pages, number_of_people_page)
```

What I want :
Each row can identify each people in the register

```
english page 1 people 1 # This people is english and registered on page 1 row 1
english page 1 people 2 # This people is english and registered on page 1 row 2
english page 1 people 3
....
english page 2 people 1
english page 2 people 2
english page 2 people 3
...
english page 11 people 1
...
french page 1 people 1
french page 1 people 1
...
```

Comment: Please try running your code once, it seems incomplete (gives error). Also can you explain your expected output? Do you want to complete the sequence from 1 to `page_number` and from 1 to `number_of_people_page` for each row ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah  I have made an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a more better approach to do this however, here is one way in base R. Assuming you have a unique nationality on each row, we can loop over each row and create a dataframe where each page number in `complete_page` is repeated `n` times + `last_page` values. For row number we repeat sequence of `1:n` `complete_page` number of times + `last_page` values.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(register)), function(i) with(register, 
   data.frame(nationality = nationality[i], 
              page = c(rep(seq_len(complete_page[i]), each = n), 
                            rep(complete_page[i] + 1, last_page[i])),
              row = c(rep(seq_len(n), complete_page[i]), seq_len(last_page[i]))))))


#    nationality page row
#1       english    1   1
#2       english    1   2
#3       english    1   3
#4       english    1   4
#5       english    1   5
#6       english    1   6
#7       english    1   7
#8       english    1   8
#9       english    1   9
#10      english    1  10
#.....
```

**data**

```
nationality <- c("english", "french", "portuguese")
complete_page <- c(10, 3, 8)
last_page <- c(5,12,1)
register <- data.frame(nationality, complete_page, last_page)
n <-  30
```

Comment: great answer using base R.